# Evitar recargar el mapa al mover los puntos en Android

Tags: android-studio, arcgis

Estoy moviendo un punto de vez en cuando, el problema es que para mantener el punto dentro del mapa y no perderse a medida que se mueve, tengo que volver a cargar el mapa. Cómo podría evitar recargarlo, ya que el movimiento ocurre cada dos segundos y el mapa se recarga cada dos segundos es demasiado incómodo.
Utilizo mapa de ArcGis para Android.

Aquí el código:

```
cont++;
    final long EXECUTION_TIME = 2000;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        int aux = 0;               
        @Override
        public void run() {

                    GraphicsOverlay graphicsOverlay1 = new GraphicsOverlay();
                    Graphic g1 = new Graphic(getLatLong(aux), attributes, sms);
                    graphicsOverlay1.getGraphics().add(g1);

                    mMap.getGraphicsOverlays().add(graphicsOverlay1);
                    map = new ArcGISMap(basemapType, getLatLong(aux).getY(), getLatLong(aux).getX(), 17);

                    mMap.setMap(map);  //Here is where the map is reloaded, some other way to avoid this burden


                    handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
}
```

)};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utilizar el metodo:`SetViewpointCenterAsync` en tu mMap y asi evitar la carga del mapa al actualizarse los puntos sobre el mapa.

> Aqui tienes la referencia al metodo:
>   https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/uwp/api-reference/html/Overload_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Xamarin_Forms_MapView_SetViewpointCenterAsync.htm

El codigo quedaria asi:

```
map = new ArcGISMap(basemapType, getLatLong(aux).getY(), getLatLong(aux).getX(), 17);

  mMap.setMap(map); 
  cont++;
  final long EXECUTION_TIME = 2000;
  final Handler handler = new Handler();

      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        int aux = 0;               
        @Override
        public void run() {

                    GraphicsOverlay graphicsOverlay1 = new GraphicsOverlay();
                    Graphic g1 = new Graphic(getLatLong(aux), attributes, sms);
                    graphicsOverlay1.getGraphics().add(g1);

                    mMap.getGraphicsOverlays().add(graphicsOverlay1);

                    mMap.setViewpointCenterAsync(new Point( getLatLong(aux).getX(), getLatLong(aux).getY(),SpatialReferences.getWgs84()),6000.0) ;
                    handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);   }   )};
```